# What is the best way to distribute a python program extended with custom c modules?

Tags: python, c, linux, macos, software-distribution

I've explored python for several years, but now I'm slowly learning how to work with c.  Using the [python documentation](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/ext/intro.html), I learned how to extend my python programs with some c, since this seemed like the logical way to start playing with it.  My question now is how to distribute a program like this.

I suppose the heart of my question is how to compile things.  I can do this easily on my own machine (gentoo), but a binary distribution like Ubuntu probably doesn't have a compiler available by default.  Plus, I have a few friends who are mac users.  My instinct says that I can't just compile with my own machine and then run it on another.  Anyone know what I can do, or some online resources for learning things like this?

Answer (score 6):

Please read up on distutils.  Specifically, the section on [Extension Modules](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/dist/describing-extensions.html).

Making assumptions about compilers is bad policy; your instinct may not have all the facts.  You could do some marketplace survey -- ask what they can handle regarding source distribution of extension modules.

It's relatively easy to create the proper distutils `setup.py` and see who can run it and who can't.

Built binary distributions are pretty common.  Perhaps you can sign up some users will help create binary distributions -- with OS-native installers -- for some considerations.

Answer (score 1):

S. Lott is right.  You should first look at distutils.  After you've learned what you need from distutils, look at [setuptools](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools). Setuptools is built on top of distutils and makes installation easy for your users.  Have you ever used easy_install or Python Eggs?  That's what's next.